# How to change Angular 5 Material input placeholder?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do you change the placeholder colour on a angular/material input placeholder?

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name">
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: placeholder's colour means text's colour?

Comment: See here and use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46315394/1791913

Comment: All the given link in comments are applicable for older version

Comment: if you want, i already answered in this post :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/49169033/9461168

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To change the color of placeholder, override the color property of .mat-form-field-placeholder like:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-placeholder{

  color:red;
}

::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-placeholder{

  color:red;
}
```

To change the color of underline:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline .mat-form-field-ripple{

  background-color:red;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline{

  background-color:red;
}
```

This works perfect.
Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/yF4kXJ500YzefLOnLKNe?p=preview

Comment: why someone down voted this? this is working perfect. let me know if you have  concerns

Comment: @FirmCitiInc could you please upvote this, someone down-voted and people will not check.thanks

Comment: I did but I don't have enough rep for it to make a difference, sorry

Comment: What's the syntax for Mat 6?

Answer (score 29):

In the last version of angular you can remove the placeholder in the input and add a mat-placeholder in the mat-form-field and custom the css with a class

html :

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text">
    <mat-placeholder class="placeholder">Search</mat-placeholder>
</mat-form-field>
```

css:

```
.mat-focused .placeholder {
    color: #00D318;
}
```

Comment: This should be the real MVP for Angular Material 6 and up.  I did the selected answer and it did nothing, also the ::placeholder and all the old ways. I am on Angular7.0.0 with Material 6.4.7 and this worked right away.  Thanks

Comment: Note: This solutions does not work in the latest version of Angular Material (v9.2.3) if you're trying to display both "mat-label" and "mat-placeholder" in the same form field.

Comment: Very frustrated because this elegant solution no longer works on angular material 9.2.4, can't believe that they didn't make the hint just of the color of the input

Comment: @Yassir Yes my post is a bit old now, it was working fine but apparently now it's not.
I think it's pity...

Answer (score 26):

I am using angular material 8.2.3 and None of the above solutions worked for me and having the following in theme.scss(material theme file) worked for me

```
.mat-input-element::placeholder{
   color: red;
}
```

conversely with piercing the following should work in component styles

```
::ng-deep .mat-input-element::placeholder{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me! Althought I had to add !important for some reason, I will make some more investigation though.

Comment: If taking this route then don't forget to add: `, .mat-select-placeholder` since selects dont have the mat-input-element but use that instead.

Comment: Works perfectly, also in Angular 12. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked For Me :-)

Answer (score 20):

**Non of the above answers worked for me in latest versions.**

Here is working solution

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label{
    color:#000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on Angular 8.2.14 and Material 8.2.3. I also added `::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline{
  background-color: seashell !important;
}` and `::ng-deep.mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: seashell !important;;
 }` to change the underline color.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me on Angular 13 too.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For angular material 5.x.x or above there is a`mat-placeholder` element you can use. You don't need to override material css classes. This aproach -I think- is the best:

```
  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" >
            <mat-placeholder style="color:brown">Enter your name here</mat-placeholder>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="material-icons">perm_identity</mat-icon>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Note: You can not use placeholder attribute in input tag at the same time with mat-placeholder element in the same mat-form-field tag.

For further information: 
https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#floating-placeholder

Answer (score 2):

What options we have?

1. `<mat-placeholder>` tag is deprecated: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatPlaceholder
2. `/deep/` selector will be deprecated soon. `::placeholder` selector is still experimental feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

So I would recommend to use input placeholder as an attribute only if your clients have modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

One solution provided by material 2 itself found in [example code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/d6fec3573cbc854d5bf67d920c5b0f8a6eef0c86/src/material-examples/form-field-label/form-field-label-example.html). I have done a sample here:

```
 <mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
   <input matInput >
 </mat-form-field>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3RvDEBUkgVQ66cCdva76?p=preview)

Comment: so simple and it works! It works on Angular 13 while the other solutions don't.

Answer (score 0):

As @mohit uprim suggested in the answer above, We can use the **shadow piercing descendant combinators** i.e. **/deep/** or **::ng-deep** or **>>>** Below is an example

```
/deep/ .mat-form-field-placeholder {
  color: #fff;   // choose the color you want
}
```

OR

```
>>> .mat-form-field-placeholder {
  color:red;
}
```

Although this method is specified in the angular docs as of now, they have mentioned that this method will soon be deprecated.
read more: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#!#-deep-

According to Angular.io documentation, the proper way of doing this is to change the **view encapsulation to none** on your component and then writing your custom styles in the css file respective to this component. Please be advised that by doing so, you are moving away from **shadow dom** and **emulated techniques(default in an angular project)** which means the styles you specify in this component may propagate to the parent/child components and may mess up the styling there too

Answer (score -3):

Angular material in itself doesn't provide any directives for setting styles.For this, you need to go old school. Just give an id/class to your input element then use pseudo class (::placeholder).
For reference : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/