# Changing the color of placeholder text of a select element

Tags: html, css

As per an answer to a stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box). I added a placeholder to html select element.

```
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden><strong style="color:white">Choose here</strong></option>
```

Now the problem is, **I want to change the color of placeholder text to white as my background is gray.** It's not accepting any styling.

[image]

Comment: I'm Sorry but the question which is linked as similar for closing my question is not resolving my problem. That is just changing the placeholder of input elements!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `::placeholder` pseudo in CSS, like this example:

```
::placeholder { color: #fff; }
```

If you want a cross-browser solution, you can use prefixes:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #fff;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #fff;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #fff;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #fff;
}
```

The `::placeholder` selector only selects the placeholder text inside your input, besides that, you can style the input itself when it is showing the placeholder using `:placeholder-show`.

Also, be aware that Firefox might show placeholder text lighter than it is supposed to display. to fix the issue you can use:

```
::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: it does not work on `select` elements, so it is not the right answer.

Comment: `select` does not have a `placeholder` attribute. Placeholders are used in elements like input and textarea.

Answer (score 0):

is it googles material design ?
if its google material design i find that this answer is your solution i dont want to take credit of someone else afford so there is the link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355190/how-to-change-angular-5-material-input-placeholder?rq=1)  
if its not  material design anyway did you try this?

```
::placeholder {
  color: white;
}
```

its called pseudo\elements 
you can read abut them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)  
the example that i wrote is taken from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_placeholder.asp)